# Is there any way to change webstorm file color?

Tags: ide, webstorm

Webstorm shows me changed files in blue but it is barely readable. How can I change this config?

[image: The screen capture of my issue.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Colors used for indicating file status (modified, added, etc.) can be changed in  `Preferences -> Editor -> Colors & Fonts -> File Status`. Seems you are using some editor color scheme (Monokai? Twilight?) that has dark blue color used for modified files. Make sure to press Save As to save a copy of your scheme - predefined schemes are not editable

Comment: Perfect answer :) Life saver...

Answer (score 0):

You can change the theme entirely using 
File -> Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> Theme
Now you can select a theme. 
Also you can tweak themes and make your own.  Check out this link
https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html